# database relation between two different server

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, relation

I have two servers and both of them contain several tables. Many of them contain relations. Now I need to join those tables and fetch data. I have no clue how to write this sort of query. Currently, I'm working in Laravel. Any suggestions will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use model relationships you can add `connection` and `table` field in your model;

```php
class User extends Model {
    public $connection = 'firstconnection';
    public $table = 'users';
    ...

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}


class Comment extends Model {
    public $connection = 'secondconnection';
    public $table = 'comments';
    ...
}
```

You can define connections in your `config/database.php`, default connection is `mysql`.

If you write raw queries you can use full table path (specify database):

```sql
SELECT * FROM db1.users JOIN db2.comments ON db1.users.id = db2.comments.user_id;
```

Note: you must have enough privileges on both tables to join and select data. If you use exists, has or semething like that where ORM needs to join two table.

Hope this helps you